# Doctrine 2 and ORM: how to cache every query for some entity?

Tags: php, caching, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm fighting with this problem a lot of time and found, that officially, I could cache only some custom queries (useResultCache(true) on Query object). But I need to cache every query in my application to some table. What about find* methods on EntityManager?...

Could somebody help me to find an elegant solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not yet supported, and you should eventually handle it in your service layer or in your extended repositories.

What you are looking for is the [second level cache as in Hibernate](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html), which basically allows you to plug in a key-value store such as redis, riak, mongodb, etc to make things blazing fast when operations are simple fetch operations.

There's a work in progress pull request at https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/580, which will probably land in Doctrine ORM 2.5, so please review that one.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;

class MyBaseRepo extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($entityManager);
        $cache       = $em->getConfiguration()->getHydrationCache();
        $this->cache = $cache ?: new ArrayCache();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        if (!$object = $this->tryFetchFromCache($id)) {
            $object = parent::find($id);
            $this->cache->save($this->generateKey($id), $object);
        }

        return $object;
    }

    protected function tryFetchFromCache($id)
    {
        if (!$object = $this->cache->fetch($this->generateCacheKey($id))) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->getEntityManager()->merge($object);
    }

    public function generateCacheKey($id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can force this to be the base repository for the ORM in your configuration while bootstrapping your app:

```
$configuration = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

$configuration->setDefaultRepositoryClassName('My\MyBaseRepo');
```

This also forces you to purge cache entries when an update/save happens for any of your entities:

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class IssueUpdateSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em  = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        if (!$cache = $em->getConfiguration()->getHydrationCache()) {
            return;
        }

        $busted = array_merge(
            $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates(),
            $uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions(),
        );

        foreach ($busted as $entityToClear) {
            $className  = get_class($entityToClear);
            $metadata   = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
            $repository = $em->getRepository($className);
            $id         = $metadata->getIdentifierValues($entityToClear);

            $cache->delete($repository->generateCacheKey($id));
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(Events::onFlush);
    }
}
```

Please note that this implementation does NOT intercept all accesses to your database for a given entity. It will not intercept lazy loading initialization caused by proxies, and it is very fragile, so please setup some proper integration tests to support it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you, please, show to me best way to cache lazy loaded entities? I will be appreciate for that :)

Comment: @AndriiVasyliev that cannot be done, that's why I told you to look at that pull request.